# Emulator doesn't show itself

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was using android API 10 2.3.3 for making my application before. It was working fine. Then i   converted my code to API 7 2.2.1. Now whenever i try to run the code, the virtual emulator doesn't show itself. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] ------------------------------
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] Performing com.kahaf.MyApp.MyAppActivity activity launch
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'TA18801WF4'
[2012-02-29 08:57:38 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'TA18801WF4'
[2012-02-29 08:57:39 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2012-02-29 08:58:25 - MyApp] Success!
[2012-02-29 08:58:26 - MyApp] Starting activity com.kahaf.MyApp.MyAppActivity on device TA18801WF4
[2012-02-29 08:58:30 - MyApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.kahaf.MyApp/.MyAppActivity }
[2012-02-29 08:58:31 - MyApp] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.kahaf.MyApp' on port 8622
```

i have tried connecting my droid too but it won't show anything either.

Comment: does it show in the list of AVD's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Console info you have posted.. Looks like the app is being installed on the device rather than emulator..

As a suggestion, Go to Run Configuration and set the target as manual and then try selecting the emulator from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your device and run again. if that is not working try restarting eclipse.